# Execute a batch file online without downloading

Tags: java

I want to execute a batch file, which is attached to something, let's say an email, using a Java plugin online without downloading it.
If there is no other way than downloading it, then I want to download it to some specific location using a code and accessing that batch file from my plugin.

I have tried using Runtime object using the url but its downloading it. Refer the code for more details:

```
url = "...." //url address of the batch file
where url.getClass() returns java.net.URL
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start "+url);
```

Expected is to execute a batch file without downloading it.

Comment: Well, the contents of the batch file would need to be downloaded anyways so I'd not bother with trying to stream it to the command line but download and run it. Downloading a file to a specific location shouldn't be any problem and there are plenty of tutorials on the net.

Comment: Are you aware of the massive security implications?

Comment: What does executing online mean? Note that JS code or Java applets included in HTML pages are downloaded to your computer and executed there, not on the server that serves those HTML pages. That's why *your* browser needs a JS engine or a Java plugin to handle those languages.

Comment: Online means without download

Comment: "Without download" means "on the server" - which would probably be kind of useless. Unless you send all the params and receive the result. But then you don't need a batch. Which is a bad idea anyway.